# What is the name of the track/music that plays from 19:56 until 21:23 in episode 15 of Darker than Black?

Tags: music, darker-than-black

I have been looking for this track for ages. It also plays in a lot of other places, like in beginning and throughout ep 16; when Mao wakes up hostage to Amber's group and meows; and in a lot of other places. What is it's name?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure to what extent this could be considered an answer to my own question, but it seems this song is one of the many unreleased tracks Darker Than Black has. I have found that many people in Youtube  comments lament about this regarding many other DTB songs.